# Aws ec2 with lb does not return 101 on websocket

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, go, nginx, websocket

i have a problem with my app.
Basically while everything runs smooth on localhost, when i deploy to aws websocket connections does not work.
The problem is that when I make an wss request on ec2 it seems it does let the response to get out of the machine ,so instead of becoming 101 and stable a connection my app hangs on pending until 1 min pass and get a timeout, then it returns 200 but no connection establish.
Api is written in go lang with gin framework and app is written in js with React framework.
While asking some people for their advise they told me that I can "wrap" an wss request with https and pass it through lb and upgrade it with nginx, but I really cannot find anything similar.
Here is my backend code

main.go

```
    {

        ws.GET("/:id", func(c *gin.Context) {
            websocket.ServeWs(c, pool)
        })
    }
```

websocket.go

```
ar upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    ReadBufferSize:  1024,
    WriteBufferSize: 1024,
    CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool { return true },
}

func Upgrade(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (*websocket.Conn, error) {
    ws, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return ws, err
    }
    return ws, nil
}

func ServeWs(c *gin.Context, pool *Pool) {

    w := c.Writer
    r := c.Request
    conn, err := Upgrade(w, r)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%+V\n", err)
    }
    client := &Client{
        Conn: conn,
        Pool: pool,
        ID: c.Param("id"),
    }

    pool.Register <- client
    client.Read()
}
```

Here is react code

```
const socket = new WebSocket(
  `${
    process.env.REACT_APP_ENV === "dev"
      ? "ws://localhost:8080"
      : "wss://api.blabla.prod"
  }/ws/${sessionStorage.getItem("userID")}`
);


let WebSocketConnect = () => {
  console.log("Attempting Connection...");

  socket.onopen = () => {
    console.log("Successfully Connected");
  };

  socket.onclose = (event) => {
    console.log("Socket Closed Connection: ", event);
    // WebSocketConnect();
  };

  socket.onerror = (error) => {
    console.log("Socket Error: ", error);
  };
};

let sendMsg = (msg) => {
  //   console.log("sending msg: ", msg);
  socket.send(msg);
};

export { WebSocketConnect, sendMsg, socket };
```

Here is nginx config

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name api.blabla.prod;

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http') {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
    location /ws {
        proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:8080";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass       "http://127.0.0.1:8080";
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be in your nginx configuration, I would replicate this for your `/ws` endpoint. Seems to be missing the `$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for`

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name goddit.pro; // change this
        location / { // You can leave it at / or set it for another location, i.e. /ws
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
                proxy_redirect off;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
}
```

The issue could also be in your javaScript, here's how you connect and upgrade.

```
window.onload = function () {
  // Somewhere in your HTML document
  var conn;
  // Then you need to connect
  function connectWs(id) {
    if (window["WebSocket"]) {
      conn = new WebSocket("wss://" + document.location.host + "/id/" + id);
      conn.onopen = function (evt) {
        var item = document.createElement("li");
        item.innerHTML = "<em>Connected to " + id + "</em>";
        log.appendChild(item);
      };
      conn.onclose = function (evt) {
        var item = document.createElement("li");
        item.innerHTML = "<em>Connection to " + id + " closed</em>";
        log.appendChild(item);
      };
      conn.onmessage = function (evt) {
        var message = JSON.parse(evt.data);
        // console.log(message);
        printMessage(message);
      };
    } else {
      var item = document.createElement("li");
      item.innerHTML = "<b>Your browser does not support WebSockets.</b>";
      log.appendChild(item);
    }
  }
  connectWs(id);
}
```

After you shared the error logs from the React console:

Close [Code 1006](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-7.4.1) is a special code that means the connection was closed abnormally (locally) by the browser implementation.

If your browser client reports close code 1006, then you should be looking at the websocket.onerror(evt) event for details.

Comment: Nothing change, again the request does pass the nginx but does not return immediatly.
If this helps the log for /ws is this

` 
[GIN] 2021/12/23 - 08:56:38 | 200 | 59.658382116s |   172.31.40.164 | GET      "/ws/admin"
Size of Connection Pool:  0
2021/12/23 08:56:38 error occurred: websocket: close 1006 (abnormal closure): unexpected EOF`

Comment: Are you sure you restarted your nginx etc with that? It was missing the headers, proxy redirect, etc.

Comment: Yup with sudo systemctl restart nginx

Comment: I updated the answer with the JavaScript implementation, I think your issue might be there

Comment: And was missing the `window.onload`, let me know if it works

Comment: Yes checking it out.Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well the first part( localhost ) is alright as before.
But again when i pass the prod url i get this  after 1 minute

(index):38 WebSocket connection to 'wss://api.prod.com/ws/admin' failed:

Comment: And the server logs?

Comment: nginx logs 
** 172.31.40.164 - - [23/Dec/2021:09:33:31 +0000] "GET /ws/admin HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36" "62.1.105.76"
 **
gin logs are two comment above :)

Comment: And it says `failed:`, what comes after that?

Comment: And I meant the go server logs, you can add some statements there, log the websocket handler

Comment: Maybe i did not state it correctly.
Go logs
`[GIN] 2021/12/23 - 09:56:07 | 200 | 59.498586114s |     62.1.105.76 | GET      "/ws/admin"`
`error occurred: websocket: close 1006 (abnormal closure): unexpected EOF`
**And react console**
`socket.js:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://api.ct-dashboard.gr/ws/admin' failed: `
`Socket Error:  Event {isTrusted: true, type: 'error', target: WebSocket, currentTarget: WebSocket,eventPhase:2..}`
`Socket Closed Connection:CloseEvent {isTrusted: true, wasClean: false, code: 1006, reason: '', type: 'close'..}`
Sorry cannot post full stack error too long.

Comment: Updated the answer with what you should log

Comment: After a lot of debugging and searching my real problem was that my lb was letting in only https request at 443 port , and by switching it to all tcp requests (ssl) at 443 port it let pass both https and wss requests.
Thanks again for your help i appreciate it.
@Wolfgang